# Oracle client compatibility

Tags: oracle

I have been looking at the Oracle documentation but I only fount it for Oracle Client 11.

Are the newer versions of Oracle backward compatibility?

I want to install the Oracle Client 21 to retrieve data from a 11g Oracle Server but also for other versions.

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/207303_1.html - and no, the 21c client isn't supported with 11g server.

Comment: If you don't have access to that portal, you can find a summary via google or in doc like https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#supported-oracle-database-versions  To connect to Oracle DB 11gR2 you will need Oracle Client libraries 19c or older.

Comment: Here are some top level documentation links for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ and https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/